# Using single loop to recode multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, networking

I have a 15 different Dataframes (yes, week 9 is missing), each responding to a different week of this particular Data Set, and i wanna do a simple recoding and renaming of them all in a loop.

My problem is that i cannot figure out how to use a loop to just add 1 more number to the names of the data. This method here works, but is quite bulky and id love to use the technique further down in this code.

```
week0 <- ifelse(NEWC0.xls <=3 & NEWC0.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week1 <- ifelse(NEWC1.xls <=3 & NEWC1.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week2 <- ifelse(NEWC2.xls <=3 & NEWC2.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week3 <- ifelse(NEWC3.xls <=3 & NEWC3.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week4 <- ifelse(NEWC4.xls <=3 & NEWC4.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week5 <- ifelse(NEWC5.xls <=3 & NEWC5.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week6 <- ifelse(NEWC6.xls <=3 & NEWC6.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week7 <- ifelse(NEWC7.xls <=3 & NEWC7.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week8 <- ifelse(NEWC8.xls <=3 & NEWC8.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week10 <- ifelse(NEWC10.xls <=3 & NEWC10.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week11 <- ifelse(NEWC11.xls <=3 & NEWC11.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week12 <- ifelse(NEWC12.xls <=3 & NEWC12.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week13 <- ifelse(NEWC13.xls <=3 & NEWC13.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week14 <- ifelse(NEWC14.xls <=3 & NEWC14.xls != 0, 1, 0)
week15 <- ifelse(NEWC15.xls <=3 & NEWC15.xls != 0, 1, 0)
```

I had something like this in mind, where it cycles through the same 15 lines but changes the name of the dataframe, but it just doesnt work out:

```
    for (i in 1:15) {        
        week[i] <- ifelse(week[i] <=3 & week[i] != 0, 1, 0))
}
```

Comment: Consider putting the dataframes in a list and using lapply instead of a for-loop. If you post a reproducible example, I will post an answer.

Comment: Your for loop isn't working because you're assigning the result of ifelse() to the i-th item of an object called week. It's not doing the text substitution you're going for.

Comment: How do you do text substitution then?

Comment: Check out the ```assign()``` function